# access file in sharepoint2013 with R

Tags: sharepoint-2013, rcurl

I am trying to access an Excel (or text) File which was uploaded to the sharepoint2013 in R.
But I have not found anything reasonable yet. Does anyone know more about it or can give me any hints?

The (fake) folder looks like this:
'https://extranet.homepage.com/sites/datafolder/Forms/AllItems.aspx'

the url of the (fake) file looks like this: 
'https://extranet.homepage.com/sites/datafolder/randomfile.txt'

If I open the the folder in my explorer:
'https://extranet.homepage.com/sites/datafolder'

Usually I access the SharePoint Site with my Web-Browser using my username and password.

Comment: This question might be of help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048979/accessing-excel-file-from-sharepoint-with-r

Comment: A few questions: are you trying to access it from R, after uploading it from R?  What is happening when you try, include details?  What browser(s) are you using to access it, and are you able to access it that way, or is that the problem?  How are the permissions for that folder set up, specifically for new documents added into it (e.g. is it set to inherit permissions, or does each file have its own, etc)?