# Issues accessing Sharepoint .xlsx file in R

Tags: r, excel, sharepoint

I am attempting to pull data from our SharePoint using the instructions found [here (StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048979/accessing-excel-file-from-sharepoint-with-r). Here is the code I am using:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel('//MyCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/MyProject/Shared Documents/MyExcelFile.xlsx',
       'Sheet1',
       skip=1)
```

When I enter *https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/MyProject/Shared Documents/MyExcelFile.xlsx* into my browser it prompts me to open the Excel document in Excel (not Excel online). So my assumption is that the link works. I have also tried using the *httr* package as such (with no luck):

```
data <- GET(url, authenticate("username","password",type="any"))
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to download some Excel files from some SharePoints. Afterwards, I was able to read the content of the Excel file afterwards. Here is an example of the code I use :

```
library(readxl)
url <- "https://sharepoint.mycompany.ca/teams/report/file.xlsx"
download.file(url = url, destfile = "D:/file.xlsx",
              mode = "wb")

read_excel("D:/file.xlsx")
```