# Read Excel file from Sharepoint in R

Tags: r, sharepoint

I am trying to access my company's Sharepoint site through R. My goal is to write a script that will be executed every month using task scheduler. This way, I will always have the most up to date version of the Excel file stored locally.

I tried the following ([based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048979/accessing-excel-file-from-sharepoint-with-r)):

```
library(readxl)
url <- "//company.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/II/FRD/AKLKIN/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7Bcc27fd87-9cdb-4e15-a6f2-22f3a6b7c831%7D&action=default&uid=%7BCC27FD87-9CDB-4E15-A6F2-22F3A6B7C831%7D&ListItemId=72&ListId=%7B2D17AD2E-9E6F-4F31-BE6E-EE317D263089%7D&odsp=1&env=prod"
Excel <- read_excel(url, sheet = "Sheet name", skip = 4)
```

But this returns:

```
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘//company.sharepoint...
```

Comment: You might try mapping the drive to a local path